# How to res.redirect to oauth url with express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I got a big problem with express.js and react. I’m trying to make google authentication via oauth2 library but I can’t get the main page redirect to auth URL from server-side. Can anyone help me out??

I've tried to send URL variable to the client but I failed, I used open (npm package) but it can't be used on lab machines where my code is.

```
aurl = (oAuth.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
    state: JSON.stringify({filename: req.file.originalname, title, description, category, audience, purpose, playlist}) }));
    desc = req.body.geoloc+":"+req.body.purpose+":"+req.body.title+":"+"language"+":"+req.body.content+":"+req.body.audience+":"+req.body.detail;
    res.redirect(aurl);
```

Then in Chrome, I get these errors:

> "GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline...
>   400" and "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline...'
>   (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/upload') from origin 'null'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.strong text